# Running feature files python behave - Pyhcharm - No Feature found

Tags: python, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

I'm having a problem running one of my feature files. I can run one of them but not the other. I have the exact same setup for run configurations for both.

```
raise ParserError(msg, None, self.filename)
behave.parser.ParserError: Failed to parse "C:\project\test.feature": 
Parser failure in state init, at line 1
REASON: No feature found.
```

If I change the configuration I get:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\pythonw.exe" -m behave "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1\helpers\pycharm\behave_runner.py"
Testing started at 16:41 ...
ConfigError: No steps directory in "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1\helpers\pycharm"
```

Comment: I'm running them in a terminal in the features folder by just using the command behave. It's not cucumber it's gherkin. Steps is inside a folder called steps and im using python

Answer (score 1):

A problem could be the file encoding. Behave does not seem to play well with utf-8 files with BOM.
For me, removing the bom worked. In Pycharm, go to File -> Remove BOM

Answer (score 0):

```
behave.parser.ParserError: Failed to parse "C:\project\test.feature": 
Parser failure in state init, at line 1
REASON: No feature found.
```

It seems you've missed to add feature name on `Feature` section in your gherkin file.

Your `test.feature` file structure should be like :

```
Feature: feature name

  Scenario: some scenario
      Given some condition
       Then some result is expected.
```

> I'm running them in a terminal in the features folder by just using the command behave. It's not cucumber it's gherkin. Steps is inside a folder called steps and im using python

Make sure your project has the proper [behave directory structure](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/gherkin.html):

```
features/
features/everything.feature
features/steps/
features/steps/steps.py
```

Try to run your script from outside features folder:

```
behave features/everything.feature
```